# Adding Hadoop dependencies to standalone Flink cluster

Tags: apache-flink

I want to **create** a **Apache Flink standalone cluster** with serveral taskmanagers. I would like to use HDFS and Hive. Therefore i have to add some **Hadoop dependencies**.

After reading the [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/ops/deployment/hadoop.html#providing-hadoop-classes), the recommended way is to set the **HADOOP_CLASSPATH** env variable. But how do i have to add the hadoop files? Should i download the source files in some directory like /opt/hadoop ont the taskmanagers and set the variable to this path?

I only know the old but deprecated way downloading a Uber-Jar with the dependencies and place it under the /lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you'd do the standard Hadoop installation, since you (for HDFS) need Node Managers running on every server (with appropriate configuration), plus the NameNode running on your `master` server.

So then you can do something like this on the `master` server where you're submitting your Flink workflow:

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=`hadoop classpath`
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf
```

Comment: But the Hadoop/Cloudera cluster is different from the fllink cluster. I want to sperate these on different machines. So i will submitting the job to the flink master, but this is not the NameNode.

Comment: Or maybe i can use the maven plugin for downloading dependencies described in [this section](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/deployment/#download-maven-dependencies-locally).